# "Windows does not appear to be on the drive from which it boots". Veracrypting corporate laptops

Tags: encryption, laptop

I work on the Help Desk of an org. I have been encrypting laptops with VeraCrypt for months now, but suddenly running into the message above in the title. The laptops getting this error don't have multiple drives. They have one C: and its listed as Boot. The only other partition, that 100MB EFI partition, is 100% free. What is going on?

Edit: This question has been asked in a few other places online, but in every one of those cases, the asker explains that he DOES have multiple drives. (Usually a main HDD and a SSD). My laptops don't, so the answers elsewhere do not apply for the most part.